# Regex to extract dates and apply it to pandas DF

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, date

I want to extract dates from a pandas DF that look something like this:

```
"{ts '2019-07-16 00:00:00'}"
```

I just need a `yyyy-mm-dd` format. I have tried using the following code to test my regex:

```
date_reg_exp = re.compile('\d{4}(?P<sep>[-/])\d{2}(?P=sep)\d{2}')

# a string to test the regular expression above
test_str= "{ts '2019-07-16 00:00:00'}"
# finds all the matches of the regular expression and
# returns a list containing them
matches_list=date_reg_exp.findall(test_str)

# iterates the matching list and prints all the matches
for match in matches_list:
print (match)
```

Output:

```
-
```

expected output:

```
2019-07-16
```

Comment: `matches_list=[x.group() for x in date_reg_exp.finditer(test_str)]`

Comment: i think i solved my problem. I kept using my test_str and changed it for the pandas column